# ES6 - Clone an object and rename its keys in one line?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, clone, destructuring

Is there a way to **destructure** or **clone** an `object` into another one, renaming it's keys in the process ?

**Example** :

```
let getUser = () => { return {first: "Radio", last: "Reve"} }
let {first: firstName, last: lastName} = getUser()

let o = {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName} // This is the line I don't wanna have to write
```

Is there an easy way to have the result stored in an object instead of two distinct variables, `firstName` and `lastName` ?

I receive an object from the server with 10 keys, and I would like to pick only 2 keys, and rename those keys, with no extra libraries nor using a special function in a native a consistent way.

Comment: `var copy = Object.assign({},getUser())`

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I added comments to clarify what I want

Comment: @Radioreve It is still a duplicate. See the first answer: "In other words, there is no way to "deconstruct from an object into an object", or "pick from an object into an object". You can only deconstruct from an object into variables."

Comment: @str alright indeed. So it's not possible... *sad face*

Comment: You can shorten that line to `{firstName, lastName}`, but indeed there's no other way than to explicitly construct the object

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible from what I searched using native language syntax, as far as I can tell.

I came up with a general solution that may help:

```
let cloneAndRename = (obj, renames) => {
    let clone = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (renames[key] !== undefined) {
            clone[renames[key]] = obj[key];
        } else {
            clone[key] = obj[key];
        }
    });
    return clone;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
let o = cloneAndRename(getUser(), {first: 'firstName', last: 'lastName'});
```

Comment: not quite what I wanted, but thanks though :) it seems it's not possible with a basic one liner and language constructs.. yet at least !

Comment: Updated my answer to say that it may not be able to be done using basic syntax just yet. However, the logic of the solution is still fine.